# Sparc Assembly - Put address into register or Put value at the adress contained in register

Tags: assembly, sparc

I just want to understand a detail with Sparc Assembly :

if do :

```
.data 
s0: .asciz "foo %s\n" 
s1: .asciz "bar" 

.text 
.global main 

main: save %sp, -96, %sp 
set s0, %o0 
set s1, %o1
```

then have I the address of `s0` and `s1` strings into respectively `%o0` and `%o1` registers ?

In general, when I do the following instruction with `I` variable :

```
set I, %g1
```

Does it mean that I put address of `I` into `%g1 register` or put `I` value at the address contained in `%g1` register ?

Sorry if this question seems to be stupid but I am beginning with Sparc assembly.

Thanks

Comment: `set` loads an immediate, which in this case is the address but could be a numeric constant too. To access memory you use the `ld*` instructions, or `st*` for stores.

Comment: @Jester : So if I do : set 100, %l7;  ld [%l7], %l0 , it affects the numeric constant "100" to %l7 ?? and ld[%l7], %l0 means that the value contained into %l7 register is stored into %l0 ?

Comment: No, as I said, `ld` accesses memory. `ld [%l7], %l0` would go to memory at address `100` (since that's what is in `%l7`) and load the word from there into `%l0`.

Comment: Thanks !  this is clearer for me